# Publicação suspensa e prestes a ser bloqueado para perguntas

Tags: debate, perguntas, suspensão

Dei uma olhada nos tópicos relacionados, mas gostaria de discutir o caso específico desta pergunta: [Como fazer para que usuário possa editar o formulário preenchido anteriormente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57084/como-fazer-para-que-usu%C3%A1rio-possa-editar-o-formul%C3%A1rio-preenchido-anteriormente).

A [outra pergunta que realizei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57169/erro-ao-ocultar-div-por-sele%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-option-em-formul%C3%A1rio-com-javascript) realmente foi um engano, mas que já me custava alguns dias de dor de cabeça. Sei que tava na cara mesmo, coloquei até o código no jsfidlle e não vi!

É claro que não justifica, e ela deve mesmo ser apagada do site, porque não resolve nada pra ninguém, e existe até uma regra específica para isso (erro de digitação do código), mas no caso que gostaria de debater (principalmente pra entender o que fiz de errado) não consegui encontrar um fundamento sólido para a suspensão da pergunta, que a meu ver atende a todos os requisitos do site.

Inicialmente concordo que ela estava meio confusa mesmo, mas agora, com a ajuda de um usuário mais experiente, que me indicou algumas alterações, acho que não tem porque continuar suspensa. Penso que i) dá pra entender perfeitamente o que quero, ii) pode ajudar outros usuários, e iii) foi respondida por dois usuários que me parecem experientes, e que solucionaram completamente minha dúvida.

Sei que por conta disso estou prestes a ser bloqueado para perguntas, e logo agora que tenho uma ótima! :)

O que gostaria de saber é se existe ainda a possibilidade desta pergunta deixar de estar suspensa, e, com isso, eu ameaçado de ser bloqueado para outras perguntas, porque embora eu não tenha sido útil para o stackoverflow até agora, ele foi extremamente útil para mim... Eu quero acertar.

Pra não criar outro tópico vou emendar outra dúvida aqui, que tem a ver com uma possível contribuição minha para a comunidade. É que eu queria fazer uma postagem sobre os aspectos jurídicos numa questão da base oficial do CEP, mas não pude por não ter reputação suficiente (e este é um assunto que eu provavelmente poderia acrescentar algo...). É um risco muito grande editar uma resposta sobre isso (o próprio usuário sugeriu que fosse editada) pra pontuar algumas coisas (como a viabilidade de um mandado de segurança), e daí atrair a ira do pessoal e ser banido de uma vez? Sabe como é né, a coisa já está muito boa pro meu lado por aqui, não quero piorar as coisas.

Por fim quero dizer que estou achando o site incrível, muito útil mesmo, e espero corrigir meus equívocos, pra quem sabe ainda contribuir com o que estiver ao meu alcance.

Comment: Tem certeza de que está "prestes a ser bloqueado para perguntas"? Vi que você tem duas perguntas suspensas, o que não é nada incomum, especialmente para um usuário novo (e as duas com pontuação zero, se estivessem bastante negativadas aí sim seria um problema). Você tem muitas perguntas deletadas? Não tenho certeza da regra, mas acho que [precisa de bem mais que isso pra um usuário ser bloqueado para perguntas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/177950). Todo mundo dá uns tropeços no início, e do meu ponto de vista você está se saindo até melhor que muitos outros novatos...

Comment: Valeu cara! O pessoal aqui parece gente boa, só estranhei talvez um excesso de rigor, mas talvez esteja enganado... Não tenho nenhuma pergunta deletada, mas quando abro a página pra postar aparece a mensagem:  "Aguarde! Algumas das suas perguntas não foram bem recebidas e você está prestes a ser bloqueado para perguntas.Para ajudar a formular uma pergunta clara e útil, consulte: Como fazer uma boa pergunta?Além disso, edite suas perguntas anteriores para melhorar a formatação e a clareza."

Comment: Eu acho que esse "prestes a" é exagero do sistema, porque eu também não vejo nada no seu perfil que te deixe à beira da suspensão (apesar de que ninguém sabe ao certo os critérios de suspensão do sistema, são *top secret*...). A sua pergunta tem sim chances de ser reaberta, mas acho fundamental um exemplo de código mostrando como você está utilizando o MySQL. Existem 3 drivers de MySQL para PHP, sendo que um deles ainda pode ser usado de duas maneiras diferentes. Então é importante você mostrar isso pra solução seguir a mesma linha.

Comment: Outra coisa: lendo os comentários, eu deixaria de fora da pergunta a questão de autenticação e uso de sessões. É um assunto independente, e se você quiser pode perguntar sobre isso em outra pergunta, senão essa fica ampla demais mesmo. Ah, no comentário anterior faltou dizer uma coisa: descreva também a estrutura do seu banco, das tabelas onde os dados do formulário são salvos.

Comment: Valeu cara, vou ver de editar a pergunta incluindo os códigos, apesar de achar isso desnecessário, porque o que eu queria mesmo saber era como um usuário pode editar o formulário respondido anteriormente, e pra isso preciso antes fazer a autenticação deles, e depois é só usar a id, como explicaram lá... Pra falar a verdade, pra mim já está bem respondida, só queria que fosse retirada a suspensão porque achei injusto mesmo, e porque pode ajudar alguém com a mesma dúvida (e claro, por causa da ameaça de suspensão do sistema quando fui querer postar outra pergunta).

Comment: Também achei exagerado esse sistema. Se o Gustavo fosse daqueles usuários mais 'estressadinhos' poderíamos ter perdido um potencial bom usuário do SOpt. @bfavaretto você não consegue retirar essa imposição do sistema pro Gustavo?

Comment: @Earendul Não, mas fique claro que ele não está bloqueado.

Comment: E esta agora: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57473/problema-com-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-php-script-pra-apurar-multa-trabalhista porque foi suspensa também?

Comment: O tópico por fim corrigiu meu problema (de novo!), mas não entendo porque ele não pode ser útil aqui (será apagado, certo?). Pelo que tenho visto o pessoal aqui é ninja mesmo, e eu só estou começando (tardiamente, mas sempre é tempo né...). Tentei fazer tudo certo nesta postagem: inclui os códigos, especifiquei ao máximo, e tentei tornar útil para outras pessoas, coloquei no título onde eu achava que estava o problema. Eu não sei mesmo se o SOpt é pra mim, pelo menos por enquanto, porque fico olhando as perguntas e pqp não tem nada que eu saiba pra responder! auahuahua - discuss?

Comment: Eu reabri essa sua última pergunta por entender que foi fechada erroneamente (é, temos esse problema aqui...). Não se trata de erro de digitação, o que você não sabia era que o `&&` é resolvido antes do `||`. Não se assuste com o site, se não existissem as perguntas, também não haveria respostas. Às vezes a gente é esquisito/chato/pedante mesmo, mas você parece estar lidando bem com isso :)

Comment: Legal cara, valeu! Eu to curtindo muito o site, e tá me ajudando demais mesmo. Espero ainda conseguir contribuir mais, e só fazer perguntas dentro do escopo. ;)

Comment: Então, depois de ler vários tópicos relacionados (v.g. gorila x tubarão :-)), acho que esta pergunta que eu criei http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57084/como-fazer-para-que-usu%C3%A1rio-possa-editar-o-formul%C3%A1rio-preenchido-anteriormente realmente não cabe aqui no SOpt (pelo menos não desta forma). Tentei editar, pra ficar dentro do escopo, mas a verdade é que não tem mais nada que eu precise saber (tenho que usar sessions primeiro, depois fazer a integração...), provavelmente não vai ajudar mais ninguém, e ficou muito geral mesmo...